# Pubnub Socket Timeout exception

Tags: java, cordova, sockets, pubnub

This is the error I get in PubNub, when I publish. I am publishing from a normal Java file on eclipse.

`[Error: 103-2] : HTTP Error. Please check network connectivity. Please contact support with error details if issue persists. : java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out`

My network is connected and is working. Ping requests to google & other servers are successful. Yet, the error keeps occurring randomly.

Comment: I know this is a bit late, maybe we solved this in private in PubNub Support but would need PubNub SDK logs to troubleshoot. https://www.pubnub.com/docs/java-se-java/pubnub-java-sdk-troubleshooting-guide